# Jquery Auto Complete Not Working in Jquery .load() File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a form that's called by $("#area").load('edit.php'). In that edit.php file, I want a field that autocompletion can be applied. I have tried to take the javascript in the edit.php file, but it's not working. And then I tried to take the javascript in the main file; it's not working either. Why? Please help me.

Here is the javascript I got from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
    "Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
```

Ps: I've also tried in a single php file (without load.()) and it's just working fine. But not with this case.

Comment: What do you see in the HTML that is rendered on the page - is being HTML encoded?

Comment: Do you see the load request to the server (as a get) with a response containing the expected HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use **HTTP or https** , infront of CDNs.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Try to put the function in window.onload() method.

```
   $(window).load(function() {
          $(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
    "Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
    });
```

And HTML should be

```
<body> 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div> 
</body>
```

Please use **inspect element** in the browser (chrome) and see whether above CDNs are loaded properly

[image]

Comment: Above code works fine . I have implemented it and 100% in working  condition :) Did you modify the **HTML** as I have done?

Comment: I've tried it in single file before and in that single file, it's working. But not with the .load() function.

Comment: Please use inspect element in the browser (chrome) and see whether above CDNs are loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

```
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js
```

I think your jquery files not loading pls copy the url and get source code and save the file in .js good luck

Comment: It's loading, because I've tried it in single file before and in that single file, it's loading. But not with the .load() function.

Answer (score 0):

All that you need are the full http paths to the scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acarlon/auEBJ/)** for a working example.

Can you see the get request for the load and do you see the correct data being loaded?

Comment: I've tried it in single file before and in that single file, it's working. But not with the .load() function.

Comment: @user1397595. If you use the dev tools for the browser (e.g. ctrl+shift+i in chrome) and look at the network requests, do you see the corresponding get for the load() and do you see the correct information being returned?

Comment: @user1397595 - also, can you show the code where you do the load?

Comment: function confirm() { $("#ganti").load('edithotel.php'); $('#boxmatch').animate({'top':'-3000px'},500,function(){
}); 
 

  $('#edithotel').animate({'top':'50px'},500,function(){
}); }

    

  

  
      $("#ganti").load('edithotel.php');

Comment: @user1397595 - do you see the request form the browser for 'edithotel.php'? Can you put a breakpoint in your server code to make sure that it is being requested. Do you see the response coming back to your browser. Once it is back, does the returned HTML look correct?

Comment: yes, it gives repons. Another html and function are working perfectly.